# permission for var/www/html directory

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I installed ubuntu server 14.04 then (apache,php and mysql).
I uploaded my website to /var/www/html and nuzip it and linked it to database.
When I request my ip in the browser i get the home page, but when click on any url in the site it returns 404 not found error - not from my website- but from the server.
I searched but problem not solved
this is what i tryed

```
chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
chown -R $user:$user /var/www/html/
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

but non of this works.
any idea ?

Comment: try with sudo command `sudo chmod -R 777 or 655 /var/www/html`

Comment: i tried but no progress

Comment: I logged in as root

Comment: is it wordpress site, php site or any framework site?

Comment: i tried with 755, but I do not think 777 is a good thing.always pepole worning me about 777 use

Comment: no its laravel website

Comment: Try making a simple web page (html) and access it. If that passes, (thinking from url rewrite perspective), make sure that .htaccess is present in document root and that mod rewrite is enabled in apache

Comment: @vishwakarma09 I said before the home page (index.php) is running perfect but when request sub url it returns 404 error. the website hes .htaccess file. I,ll search about rewrite mod.

Comment: It may be your DNS is wrong as well.  The site working by IP but not working by name means either DNS is wrong, or the apache config is wrong.  It can't possibly be related to file permissions or location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by running this command

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart apache server.

Thanks to everybody tryed to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel, please keep in mind that you have to separate "public" folder and the app itself.

First of all, go to `/var/www` and create folder called "app".

Put everything in here excluding public folder.

Contents of public folder goes to `/var/www/html`.
Now, edit routes in `/var/www/html/index.php`

From `__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php` to `../app/bootstrap/app.php`

Do the same with other routes in here.

Don't forget to change the permissions. The easiest way would be to set it to 777 for the whole /var/www using `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www`

Good luck.

Comment: "chmod 777" is such a terrible idea.

Comment: @user3137702 you are right, but that's not the topic of this question. I said it's the easiest way, not the most secure.